# Can no longer mount a DLINK DNS-323 NAS drive on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mount, dns, cifs

I have a problem where once I was able to simply mount a NAS drive either in using fstab or standalone. I am able to do this on Windows with no issues, but can not on Linux.

Furthermore, I have tried every mount possibility but nothing works. What I have so far is one

sudo nano /etc/fstab

```
//10.0.0.XXX/Volume_1 /home/richard/Documents/DLINK.Volume_1 cifs vers=1.0,username=admin,password=


//10.0.0.XXX/Volume_2 /home/richard/Documents/DLINK.Volume_2 cifs vers=1.0,username=admin,password=
```

Notice I have two drives and expecting to mount both drives. Even individually, it still does not work. Curiously, if I mount a normal Windows Drive I have no issues, but with this, I get an error such as

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Sure I have the right drive which I use the same on Windows.

I have spent hours and days on this, wanted to revisit it because I find it very frustrating. Looked everywhere on the net with no avail. Is there somebody in this world that has an answer?

N.B. It is an old DLINK DNS-323 NAS it might be basically a DNS, but I am not sure if I just want it to work.

The closest I got to an answer on the internet which is only for the CentOS operating system is to install samba3-cifsmount

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401607/cifs-vfs-cifs-mount-failed-w-return-code-22-and-wrong-fs-type-bad-option?rq=2

Can someone tell me how to do this in Ubuntu 20.04, please?

Another point can do this with no problem using Lubuntu 22.04, Curious thing though does not work for my Windows Disk bay drives on it.